# Reference to pointers and C++ polymorphism

Tags: c++, reference, polymorphism, pointers, parameters

does anyone know why this gives a compiler error ? I tried VS 2005 and Codewarrior:

```
class Parent {
   protected:
      int m_Var;
   public:
      Parent() : m_Var(0) {}
      virtual ~Parent() {}
      void PubFunc();
};

class Child : public Parent {
   protected:
      bool m_Bool;
   public:
      Child() : m_Bool(false) {}
      virtual ~Child() {}
      void ChildFunc();
};

void RemoveObj(Parent *& ppObj)
{
   delete ppObj;
   ppObj = 0;
}

int main()
{
   Parent* pPObj = 0;
   Child*  pCObj = 0;
   pPObj = new Parent();
   pCObj = new Child();

   RemoveObj(pPObj);
   RemoveObj(pCObj);
   return 1;
}
```

Visual studio says:

> refptr.cpp(33) : error C2664:
>   'RemoveObj' : cannot convert parameter
>   1 from 'Child *' to 'Parent *&'

Thanks

Answer (score 16):

The `ppObj` parameter to RemoveObj is a reference to a Parent*.  What if the the `RemoveObj()` method replaced the pointer with a pointer to a new `Parent` object?  When the method returned your the `pCObj` `Child*` would not be pointing to a `Child` object any more.

Answer (score 4):

From the C++ standard (1998)

> Except in the context of an
>   initialization by user-defined
>   conversion (13.3.1.4, 13.3.1.5), a
>   well-formed  implicit conversion
>   sequence is one of the following
>   forms:  —a standard conversion
>   sequence(13.3.3.1.1), -a user
>   defined...

13.3.3.1.1

> At most one  conversion from each
>   category is allowed in a single
>   standard conversion sequence

So c++ can NOT convert implicitly two times in a row: from pointer to pointer and then again from pointer.

To clear this up consider such declaration of the RemoveObj

```
void RemoveObj(Parent ** ppObj)
```

And you will see this error

```
error: invalid conversion from 'Child**' to 'Parent**'
```

You have to use explicit conversion like

```
   RemoveObj((Parent**)&pCObj);
   RemoveObj((Parent*&)&pCObj);
```

or have to change

```
void RemoveObj(Parent *& ppObj)
```

to

```
void RemoveObj(Parent * ppObj)
```

or to

```
template <typename T>
void RemoveObj(T *& pObj)
{
   delete pObj;
   pObj = 0;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer why it is a complier error, but it is what it should be changed to be.  The reference to the pointer is not necessary to do what the method is doing.

Comment: I've adder reference to the standard.

Comment: With the edit, this is definitely an answer as to why you're getting a compiler error. You're attempting a two-step conversion which is illegal according to the portion of the standard @MykolaGolubyev pointed out. Unfortunately, a `reinterpret_cast` is the most practical solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

ppobj is the reference for the pointer.
*ppobj dereferences what the variable points to, so you get the variable the pointer.

Since the dereference is not of the correct type you are seeing the error.

Answer (score 0):

A pointer to a reference allows the pointer value to change in the function. As noted by [Michael Burr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12711/michael-burr) there would be the potential to assign an incorrect class reference and return it. Imagine your entire program incorrectly using *pchickens as *peggs :)

I thought it was worth adding (although not explicitly what you asked):
My preference for a polymorphic implementation is to move common functions inside as a methods. If they all share a function, simple add it the base class.

Then either way you could simply call
Foo->Bar() and achieve the desired result. But for the specific implementation example you give, simply delete Foo would call the appropriate destructor.

Answer (score -2):

This is not authoritative, but I believe the problem is the polymorphic nature of C++ classes does not extend to their pointers; what you are expecting to be done here is for a `Child *` to be cast to a `Parent *`; while you can cast a `Child` to a `Parent`, you cannot cast the pointer **reference**.  That is, the classes are polymorphic, but the pointers to the classes are not when taken as references.  This is for the reason that Michael Burr gives above; the `Child *` implies a certain memory structure that the `Parent *` does not.

Comment: conversion between pointers are possible. the conversion however returns an rvalue temporary. which is the reason it can't be passed to a non-const reference.

Comment: The problem is from the reference, not the pointers.  You can pass the pointers interchangeably, but not a reference to a pointer of a different type pointer.

Comment: I think you were talking about conversions of lvalues to lvalues w.r.t Child* to Parent*. You are right such a conversion isn't possible. But your post sounds like you are implying that Child* to Parent* is disallowed (it isn't). Didn't downvote, just helping you figure out why they could have downvoted you. (if they only told you...)

Comment: @litb: thx for the clarification on the interpretation; edited to make it a bit clearer.

Comment: You can do this experiment: void f(Parent * const& p); you can call it with f(pChild); because the result of the implicit pointer conversion to Parent* can be bound to the parameter p: it's a non-const reference. Since we are not operating "polymorphic" here (we are not saying "the argument Child* pointer is the parameter Parent* pointer") but rather on a copy, this will work fine. I believe this is what you meant.